# How to pass request headers to the web socket request response sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I receive some response headers:

```
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: zi1DDwu1UMCCUC1nJX/k65L6jfQ=
Upgrade: websocket
```

as a result of web socket open connection
[response header of websocket open connectiob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCCzD.png)
and now need to pass it to the request headers of the request response sampler as right now in the above image
[request header of response sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD8pw.png)
there are no request headers shown
but for HTTP request it is coming (check for [request header of HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t86Jn.png)

I tried passing the values to the header manager but it is not passing to websocket sampler they are passing for only HTTP request.

I want that request headers to be passed to the web socket request response sampler

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything.

The [WebSocket Samplers plugin by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) [automatically handles `Sec-WebSocket-Key`](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/e7a694f4f98aa83541a80fe1e64c0761b00db5ce/src/main/java/eu/luminis/websocket/WebSocketClient.java#lines-196) and `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` headers, moreover it even [checks that the latter one has its anticipated value](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/e7a694f4f98aa83541a80fe1e64c0761b00db5ce/src/main/java/eu/luminis/websocket/WebSocketClient.java#lines-509).

You can see the outgoing headers by either using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [enabling debug logging for the WebSocket Samplers plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change, once done you will be able to see request and response details in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Comment: If headers are going or calculated at runtime , then why my request is giving sucess code but not proper response is coming